# Using native library in external classes loaded dynamically (with reflection)

Tags: android, reflection, android-ndk, runtime, android-native-library

In my application, I'm using `DexClassLoader` to load a class of an external apk as follow:

```
DexClassLoader dexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader("path/to/someApkfile.apk", myOptimizedDirectory, null, myContext.getClassLoader());
Class<?> MyClass =  dexClassLoader.loadClass("its.package.name.MyClass");
```

Then invoking a method using reflection as follow:

```
Object myInstance = MyClass.newInstance();
MyClass.getDeclaredMethod("foo").invoke(myInstance);
```

here is the method `foo`:

```
public void foo() {
 System.Load("path/to/arch/specific/native/lib/libname.so");
 // I know that this native library loaded successfully because JNI_OnLoad is called.

 // here is the problem
 int result = myNativeMethod("arg");
}
```

And here the `myNativeMethod`:

```
private native int myNativeMethod(String arg);
```

Here is the log message:

```
mMessages: uncaught exception
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int its.package.name.MyClass.myNativeMethod(java.lang.String) (tried Java_its_package_name_MyClass_myNativeMethod) ...
```

I am sure that the method signature in my native code is correct and nothing is wrong there.

Also, I'm sure that it successfully loaded native library, so why does it say `No implementation found`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you will get same error even if you don't *invoke* the method **foo()**. That's because Java must resolve the native methods when it loads the class, does not defer this until the actual native method is called.

Comment: Are you using Proguard to shrink the code? Maybe the ProGuard obfuscation procedure has changed the name of that method. Try to add "STATIC" in the native declaration: "private static native int myNativeMethod(String arg);" because from the error log I don't understand if the "MyClass.myNativeMethod(..)" refers to a try to read a STATIC method or not.

Comment: @AlexCohn belive me, there is no error till calling `myNativeMethod`. I think it resolves the native methods but fail to link them.

Comment: @emandt Progrard is disabled in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I faced similar issue when tried to get objecy's ClassLoader using Object.getClassLoader() and tried to get Object's Methods that are not found. I solved this issue by using "ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()" instead of "myContext.getClassLoader()" for "parent" parameter.